# How to get data of an specefic row or column in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

Example

```
id name surname
0  Alex A
1  Mark B
2  Bill C
```

Let's suppose that I want to get the name and surname where id equals 1 in Java, how can I get the values of each column

Comment: You use JDBC: [The Java™ Tutorials - JDBC(TM) Database Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Statement or PreparedStatement you can retrieve fields as below provided you should have included jdbc library in your project

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // loading driver class
    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database_name", username,password); // getting connection may change depending on database you are using
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("select name,sirname from user where id = ?");

                ps.setString(1,id);

             ResultSet rs =   ps.executeQuery();
                int i=0;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    //  retrieve your fields
                }

}catch(Exception e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you want to show someone, who apparently doesn't even know JDBC exists, how to use JDBC, you should at least give a good example for how is *should* be used, e.g. using try-with-resources. Besides, someone who doesn't know JDBC won't find that useful anyway, because they don't know what `cn` is. But, since StackOverflow is not a teaching site, this is off-topic anyway.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for advice I have added some more data.